# How to show one alert at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have several input fields on which I am trying to put a validation, like if that field is not filled so show some alert to user when user clicks on save button

So I have created a function inside which I am checking the field values and when user is clicking on save then calling that function and then saving data, When i click on save I am checking for validation and after that asking user `do you want to save data` and saving,But my issue is when I click on save and if any `input field` is not filled then both the alerts are showing one by one, I want when there is some field which is empty then user will only get that alert

**Code**

```js
function validation() {

  if ($('#nameInput').val() == '') {
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'please enter First Name',
      onDestroy: function() {

        $('#nameInput').focus();
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
  if ($('#lastNameInput').val() == '') {
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'please enter Last Name',
      onDestroy: function() {

        $('#lastNameInput').focus();
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
  if ($('#classInput').val() == '') {
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'please enter class',
      onDestroy: function() {

        $('#classInput').focus();
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
}

$("#save").click(function() {

  validation()

  $.confirm({
    title: '',
    content: 'Do you want to Save Data ?',
    buttons: {
      Yes: function() {



        $.confirm({
          title: 'Message',
          content: 'Data Saved',
          buttons: {
            ok: function() {}
          },
          onDestroy: function() {

          }
        });
      },

      No: function() {

      },

    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="form-row">

  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="nameInput">First Name</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="nameInput" id="nameInput">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="lastNameInput">Last Name</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="lastNameInput" id="lastNameInput">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="classInput">Class</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="classInput" id="classInput">

    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<button type="button" class="commonButton" id="save">
    Save
    </button>
```

Check my Snippet to get working code

**Note** i am not using required HTML attribute because I have to specify which field is empty and give a alert to that field not a common alert for each field, And also I am saving data on click event not on form submit because I have several buttons for different tasks

Comment: Do you want a unique alert with all errors displayed at once or just the first error encountered?

Comment: *i am not using required HTML attribute* and *I am saving data on click event not on form submit* - you're most probably doing it wrong if you insist on bypassing any support HTML offers for your job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your code: basically run confirm only if validation is success.

```js
function validation() {

  if ($('#nameInput').val() == '') {
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'please enter First Name',
      onDestroy: function() {

        $('#nameInput').focus();
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
  if ($('#lastNameInput').val() == '') {
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'please enter Last Name',
      onDestroy: function() {

        $('#lastNameInput').focus();
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
  if ($('#classInput').val() == '') {
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'please enter class',
      onDestroy: function() {

        $('#classInput').focus();
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

$("#save").click(function() {

  if (validation()) {

    $.confirm({
      title: '',
      content: 'Do you want to Save Data ?',
      buttons: {
        Yes: function() {



          $.confirm({
            title: 'Message',
            content: 'Data Saved',
            buttons: {
              ok: function() {}
            },
            onDestroy: function() {

            }
          });
        },

        No: function() {

        },

      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="form-row">

  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="nameInput">First Name</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="nameInput" id="nameInput">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="lastNameInput">Last Name</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="lastNameInput" id="lastNameInput">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="classInput">Class</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="classInput" id="classInput">

    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<button type="button" class="commonButton" id="save">
    Save
    </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if your validation didn't passed False, then execute the save code.

```js
function validation() {

  if ($('#nameInput').val() == '') {
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'please enter First Name',
      onDestroy: function() {

        $('#nameInput').focus();
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
  if ($('#lastNameInput').val() == '') {
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'please enter Last Name',
      onDestroy: function() {

        $('#lastNameInput').focus();
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
  if ($('#classInput').val() == '') {
    $.alert({
      title: 'Alert!',
      content: 'please enter class',
      onDestroy: function() {

        $('#classInput').focus();
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

$("#save").click(function() {

  var isValid = validation();
  if (isValid) {
  $.confirm({
    title: '',
    content: 'Do you want to Save Data ?',
    buttons: {
      Yes: function() {



        $.confirm({
          title: 'Message',
          content: 'Data Saved',
          buttons: {
            ok: function() {}
          },
          onDestroy: function() {

          }
        });
      },

      No: function() {

      },
    }
  });
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="form-row">

  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="nameInput">First Name</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="nameInput" id="nameInput">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="lastNameInput">Last Name</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="lastNameInput" id="lastNameInput">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
    <label for="classInput">Class</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="classInput" id="classInput">

    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<button type="button" class="commonButton" id="save">
    Save
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all should not use alert box as it blocks the JS execution.
What you can do is, that after form validation if any input field is invalid or left empty, you can highlight the input field with a red border, indicating the user that the field has not been filled correctly and display an appropriate error message next to the input field instead of alert box :)